# rewrite url doesn't include layout?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm currently trying to make SEO friendly url's for my website using this script:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^show/([0-9]+)/$ show.php?phto=$1
RewriteRule ^index/$ index.php
```

So i've tested some things, and i've came up with these problems:
When i visit my website : `blalba.com/index/` my layout file wouldn't include/show up. (using an layout.inc.php header/footer system)

Also how can i make it that the user can visit it with `index` and `index/`

I'm not so good at this..

Grz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your rule with this code (to make trailing slash optional):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^show/([0-9]+)/?$ show.php?phto=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^index/?$ index.php [L,QSA,NC]
```

Also make sure for including style, js, images etc always use absolute path i.e. it should start with `/` or `http://`.

Comment: It seems to work, only need to edit my website a bit for the absolute path! Thanks

Comment: Seems to still have a problem or it's just me. When i visit my album with `album` it will show the pictures. But when i type `album/` my image path would be `album/thumb/thumb_3-2013090614:12:23.jpeg` instead of `thumb/thumb_3-2013090614:12:23.jpeg` how can i solve this?

Comment: Right that is very normal problem with using pretty URLs. That is how browser resolved path to resources. As I mentioned in my answer: `Also make sure for including style, js, images etc always use absolute path i.e. it should start with / or http://.` So better use `/thumb/thumb_3-2013090614:12:23.jpeg` as the path for your image and then no rewrite rule will ever affect it.

Comment: i save my path like this in my database `./thumb/thumb_3-2013090614:12:23.jpeg` so this is the problem? Should i remove the .?

Comment: Yes removing `.` should work. I guess full path is: `/thumb/thumb_3-2013090614:12:23.jpeg`